# Chrome Language won't change - How do I change Accept-Language?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Recently I have been having a problem. I started learning a new language a couple of Month ago (Swedish) and decided to set some stuff up in Swedish. I cant remember what settings I changed to Swedish but I changed a few settings in Google and chrome on my android phone to set the language to Swedish for language learning. But recently I decided to change everything back to English.

The problem I am having is that even though I have now set every single Google setting I can think of back to English including G+, chrome settings, clearing caches, chrome settings (desktop+android) and also Google settings in android, for some reason the default language on web-pages is still Swedish even if I'm not logged in, and even if I change the website language manually by going to the bottom of the page when I come back later it will be back to Swedish. Also all CAPTCHA e.g. "I am not a robot" etc are in Swedish and many Google apps and web-pages are as well even if I am signed in such as the Chrome app store.None of my settings now include Swedish as a secondary language and yet websites still display in it. I tried to look further by using the website validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/. This shows me that `Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7` basically that Swedish language is preferred, why?

Tried:

- Changing all Google language settings to English
- Changing Chrome settings to English
- Setting Android settings to English
- Reinstalling Chrome
- Clearing Cache & Cookies

This problem is legitimately melting my brain at this point as it affects my experience on multiple devices and sometimes websites don't have manual language selection, this is why I suspect it is to do with Google settings or locales but I have changed **all** settings I could find to do with language.And no, the "Quick Language Switcher" app doesn't do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

[Picture Of Validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5JLL.png)

[My Problem Shown On Chrome Store (I blanked my mail address)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iFMw.png)

[Chrome Language Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hWih.png)

[Google Account Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZOum.png)

(also I'm sorry if I have tagged this wrong - I'm not sure which ones to use)

Comment: This answer - changing preferences file -- helped me "purge" Danish:
https://superuser.com/questions/880742/language-selection-not-working-chrome-browser